# Notification after a time

Tags: java, android, time, notifications, wait

I want to add a Notificationmanager which should start after some milliseconds.
Everything is running, but still I don't knoe how to add the time that the notification comes after some weeks for example?

```
public void test(){
    int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
    CharSequence ticker ="ticker";
    long showAt =System.currentTimeMillis();
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, ticker, showAt);activity/intent
    CharSequence notificationTitle = "test";
    CharSequence notificationMessage = "Test1";
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity.class);
    PendingIntent objPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(ctx, notificationTitle, notificationMessage, objPendingIntent);
    final int notificationIdentifier = 101; //an unique number set by developer to identify a notification, using this notification can be updated/replaced
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationIdentifier, notification);
    // ... 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Alarm manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) with notification for repeating your notification after a regular time interval. Check [AlarmManagerNotificationManagerTutorial](http://code.google.com/p/android-ref-examples/wiki/AlarmManagerNotificationManagerTutorial) , [Android AlarmManager tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/09/android-alarmmanager-tutorial.html)  and [Multiple Notifications Using AlarmManager](http://lokeshatandroid.blogspot.ca/2012/05/multiple-notifications-using.html) . There are many tutorials out there. Hope this helps.

Comment: how can I only make one notification without repeating?? Now it repeats the notification every 6 seconds